# can't uninstall opera. everytime i try says "can't find the package" but i still can see and use opera

Tags: apt, dpkg, uninstall, opera

here i leave every try:

```
rebeca@lasuperpcderebeca:/etc$ sudo dpkg --remove opera

dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove opera which isn't installed

rebeca@lasuperpcderebeca:/etc$ sudo apt remove opera-stable

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/redis.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/redis.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/redis.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/redis.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/redis.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/redis.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/redis.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/redis.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/redis.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/redis.list:1
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/redis.list:1
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/redis.list:1
E: Unable to locate package opera-stable

rebeca@lasuperpcderebeca:/etc$ sudo apt purge opera-stable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package opera-stable
rebeca@lasuperpcderebeca:/etc$ sudo rm -f /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera-stable.list
rebeca@lasuperpcderebeca:/etc$ sudo dpkg -r opera
dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove opera which isn't installed
rebeca@lasuperpcderebeca:/etc$ sudo apt-get remove --purge opera-stable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package opera-stable
```

Comment: We don't know what OS/release you're using, being limited to details you provide. The package name is what matters here, and it can differ to the name you see in menus; eg. Ubuntu's desktop is GNOME and the File Manager of GNOME is called `nautilus` thus that's the package name, but file menus show it as File Manager (what it is). There are also package types, you show using `apt` commands which apply only to *deb* installed packages; your Opera may have been a different package type too.

Comment: Are you sure opera is installed?

Comment: If Opera is installed as a *snap* package the command is `snap remove opera`, if Opera is installed as a *flatpak* package the command is ... etc.   You've not told us HOW OPERA was installed; as the method of install will dictate the method of removal; as *deb* packages are only one way, *snap* another, *flatpak*, *compiled from source* etc... with many alternative methods of install.  FYI:  You've not provided release details, so we don't even know what your system has available as easy install options & thus what is more likely!

Answer (score 0):

My way is not a very good way but it was helpful for me,
When you want to install opera with apt it says some packages are going to install you should copy that packages names and then type `sudo apt autoremove all-packages-names`

Hope it helped

Comment: how can i find those packages?

Comment: When you want install an app for first time using apt terminal shows some package names and says these are going to install. Try it yourself and tell me if you have any problems : )

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo apt remove opera*
```

Comment: rebeca@lasuperpcderebeca:~$ sudo apt remove opera*
[sudo] password for rebeca: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package opera*
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'opera*'